# How to open a tkinter window that is in an other file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I recently started working on a program in python using Tkinter and now I want to open it from another file.
I have a home page file named `HomePage.py` that will have a button to open another file, called `VirusTotalAPI.py`. I didn't find any answers because when I run the program, it opens the `VirusTotalAPI.py` file, and if I close it the `Homepage.py` will run, but the button won't work and if I try to close it, it will open the `HomePage.py`.

```py
#Homepage.py

from tkinter import *
import VirusTotalAPI as vt 

Home_Window=Tk()

Home_Window.geometry("980x530")
Home_Window.title("VirusTotal By Carotide")
Home_Window.config(background="grey")

def Window_35_mo() : 
    vt.Window_35mo
    
Window_35_mo_open = Button()
Window_35_mo_open.config(text= "Fichier < 35 mo", command= Window_35_mo)
Window_35_mo_open.pack()

Home_Window.mainloop()
```

The next one is a part from the VirusTotalAPI.py because the file is too long

```py
#VirusTotalAPI.py
import requests
import hashlib
import json
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import HomePage

Window_35mo = Tk()
Window_35mo.geometry("980x530")
Window_35mo.title("VirusTotal By Carotide")
Window_35mo.config(background="grey")


global files
global file_path

def retrieve_API():
    API_Value=GetAPIBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(API_Value)

GetAPIBox=Text(Window_35mo, height=2, width=10)
GetAPIBox.pack()
API_Button=Button(Window_35mo, height=1, width=10, text="YourAPI", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_API())

API_Button.pack()
Window_35mo.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.
I tried to import it by different ways like this:

```py
import VirusTotalAPI
```

Or this:

```py
from VirusTotalAPI import *
```

I tried to do this too:

```py
from tkinter import *
from VirusTotalAPI import Window_35mo

Home_Window=Tk()

Home_Window.geometry("980x530")
Home_Window.title("VirusTotal By Carotide")
Home_Window.config(background="grey")
#homepage 
def winopen35mo() :
    Window_35mo
    
Window_35_mo_open = Button()
Window_35_mo_open.config(text= "Fichier < 35 mo", command= winopen35mo)
Window_35_mo_open.pack()

Home_Window.mainloop()
```

And it told me this:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Window_35mo' from partially initialized module 'VirusTotalAPI' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: put the `import VirusTotalAPI` inside `Window_35_mo`. Then you can use `VirusTotalAPI.Window_35mo`.

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work if u need any clarifications feel free to ask

Comment: The question does not make sense. Windows are not "in" the files.

Comment: So, basically the question was how to open an other whole window with everything it has on and this by linking them together and when clicking on a button it will go to the other  window that was in another file but I already found a solution. Thanks for telling me that I will make sure to ask my question better next time and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to do it there is the solution :

First we need to import os, subprocess and sys

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import subprocess
import sys
```

Then,we declare the file path of the file, for this one it is `VirusTotalAPI.py` by doing so :

```
GUI_VirusTotalAPI_Path = 'C:\\Users\\...\\VirusTotalAPI.py'
```

Now we enter the args, to execute and enter the path name :

```
args = '"%s" "%s" "%s"' % (sys.executable,                  
                          GUI_VirusTotalAPI_Path,                     
                          os.path.basename(VirusTotalAPI))
```

We are almost there, now we create a function to run this using the args we previoulsy used :

```
def Open_GUI_VirusTotalAPI_35mo() :
   proc = subprocess.run(args)
```

Then another function to destroy the window :

```
def DestroyHomeWindow() : 
    Home_Window.destroy
```

Finally we create the button and "tell" it to execute the command `Open_GUI_VirusTotalAPI_35mo`and at the same time close the window :

```
Window_35_mo_open = Button()
Window_35_mo_open.config(text= "Fichier < 35 mo", command= lambda:[Home_Window.destroy(),Open_GUI_VirusTotalAPI_35mo()])
Window_35_mo_open.pack()
```

And this is how I did it, sorry for the poor explanation and my bad english, hope this helped some people.